# Adding DOI goes out of the page

Tags: lyx, doi

I am using LyX for my CV. When I add my list of publications, many of them contain DOI's. And the problem is that when I generate the PDF, the DOI's are not "cut" or "hyphened", so that line contains and gets out of the page. How can one fix this?

Comment: Before the bibliography is added, write `\raggedright` into an ERT box.

Comment: thanks but the problem is that I add my publications "by hand", not using bibtex

Comment: Well then add a line break by hand.

Comment: how do you mean exactly "by hand"?

Comment: @flow use \\ to add line break, I guess

Comment: Yes, adding a line break by hand is what i meant.

Comment: If the `url` and/or `hyperref` are loaded, you could also enclose the doi string in a `\url{...}` wrapper.

Comment: Seems like a minimal working example would be of great help here. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: We definitely need an MWE. There are many ways of adding the publications "by hand", each of which may have their optimal solutions.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution, if you add DOIs by hand is to use the `hyperref` package in your preamble: `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Each URL or DOI has to be given in the following format: `\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-531-92180-8}{doi:10.1007/978-3-531-92180-8}`. This should create linebreaks where needed.

Comment: looks more like a DOI/ISBN hybrid to me. and wouldn't the `/` be a marker to hyphenate?

Comment: Well, I think it does not matter at all if the DOI is a hybrid. Since any DOI can be wirtten as a http-link (e.g. `http://doi.org/10.1000/182`), they can be wrapped with a `\href{}{}`-command.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a "\breaking slash" macro via  `Insert -> Math -> Macro`. Define the macro boxes as follows:

```
Macro name: \brslash
TeX        :/\allowbreak
LyX        :/
```

The result in LyX will be

[image]

So in LyX, enter math mode (`Insert -> Math -> Inline formula`) then `\text` (followed by a space bar) to enter plain text in math mode, and then type the DOI. Instead, however, of directly typing a slash, type `\brslash`. LyX can even have it autocompleted.

A similar macro can be defined for the dash `-` also.